# Understanding spark optimisation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have the following simple transformations using pyspark dataframes:

```
def join_one(df_1, df_2):
    df = df_1.alias("d1").join(df_2.alias("d2")).select("d1.InvoiceNo","d1.StockCode","d1.Description","d2.CustomerID","d2.Country")
    return df

def join_two(df_1, df_2):
    df = df_1.alias("d1").join(df_2.alias("d2")).select("d1.InvoiceDate","d1.UnitPrice","d2.Quantity")
    return df

df_1 = spark.read\
.option("header", "true")\
.csv(path_1)

df_2 = spark.read\
.option("header", "true")\
.csv(path_2)

df_3 = join_one(df_1, df_2)
df_4 = join_two(df_1, df_2)

df_3.show()
df_4.show()
```

So basically using the same two dataframes to join and then selecting different columns from the result. Now my question is that does spark automatically optimize the plan to use the same join for both the functions and then selecting the relevant columns. Or that the join operation here is going to be performed twice and myself as the user will have to optimize such operations?

Answer (score 2):

In your case Spark is going to calculate join two times.

If you want to skip second read/compute you can try to cache your joined dataset